# Memcache alternatives for App Engine Standard second generation runtimes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google has released the general availability versions of their [second generation runtimes for App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/announcing-cloud-run-the-newest-member-of-our-serverless-compute-stack) including Node.js 10, Go 1.11, and PHP 7.2.

First generation runtimes included a Memcache service that has been removed in the second generation runtimes, [recommending developers to use an external provider like Redis Lab Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences), a service that is not available in the europe-west region. Cloud Memorystore would be is not [even accessible from App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex?hl=es-419).

Is there any other alternative to replace Memcache in the new runtimes? Our system relies heavily on that service, and while we are eager to migrate from PHP 5 to 7 the lack of a reliably and fast cache system is stopping us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with App Engine standard to connect to Cloud Memorystore is the inability to connect to a specific VPC (where the Memorystore instance has its network peered).

There is a beta release for [Serverless VPC access](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/connecting-vpc) to fix exactly that.

According to the first paragraph of that doc:

> Using Serverless VPC Access, you can connect from your **App Engine app** directly to Compute Engine VM instances, **Cloud Memorystore instances**, Cloud SQL instances, and any other resources with an internal IP address.

Comment: So Google is charging now for the cache service AND the connector to that service? This is a huge step backwards from first generation runtimes where the memcache service was ready to use with no configuration and totally free.

Comment: I guess that using Cloud Memorystore is more similar to the Dedicated Memcache ($0.06 per GB per hour) than Shared Memcache (the free one). Also, if you use <100Mbps, the `f1-micro` equivalent instance seems like it could go into the [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/).